# Concatenate formatting when dynamically referencing external sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function, worksheet

I'm trying to write some code to automate a search we carry out at my company over 64 spreadsheets, with 6 sub-sheets apiece. Due to the typical large-company 'left hand, right hand' issues and due to strict policy, merging the spreadsheets is not an option. As such I'm looking at one spreadsheet which searches for a given business name across all spreadsheets, however while creating a direct link to each individual spreadsheet and sub-sheet works, I'm trying to generate the sub-sheets dynamically.

Code linking to the spreadsheet directly:
Using SumProduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]Irregularities'!$A:$A=J5))
```

Using VLookup:

```
=(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(J5,'\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]Irregularities'!$A:$A,1,FALSE)=J5,"Yes","No"),"No"))
```

In this case 'J5' refers to the cell being used for the search (in this case 'Megginson ', and the search runs fine.

[Direct links - code working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz323.png)

However when trying to generate the links dynamically I've been trying to concatenate the address so I can generate the references to the sub-sheets dynamically. This is the code I'm using for SumProduct trying to generate it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("'\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]" & Lists!A2:A7 & "!$A:$A=" & $J$5  ))
```

(note: For any further screenshots 'Lists!A2:A7' will be 'Lists!:A2' to improve readability)

However this code generates a #value error. Now, according to the formula evaluation box the code is generating the links to the sheets as an array, so that's working fine. This is what the evaluation box shows before it generates the #value error:

[sumproduct not working - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NFER.png)

Now I noticed that the "megginson " part at the end appears to be losing its quotation marks, which I thought could be the cause, so I amended the end of the SumProduct code to this:

```
"!$A:$A=" & CHAR(34) & $J$5 & CHAR(34)
```

But this is now what the evaluation is showing before generating the error

[sumproduct not working - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NByM1.png)

Where now it appears that there's too many quotation marks at the end. I've tried varying combinations of adding quotation marks around the J5 reference, but none of them solve the issue.

I've also attempted to use VLookup instead, using this code for dynamically generating the links:

```
=VLOOKUP(J5,"\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]" & "Irregularities!" & "$A:$A",1,FALSE)
```

which also generates the same #value error.

This is the formula evaluation for VLookup before it fails

[not working - VLookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAYfn.png)

This one's really confusing me, as I can't functionally see any difference between the output between the code that directly links to the irregularities spreadsheet and to the one that attempts to generate the link dynamically, aside from the presence of the quotation marks (which I assume disappear when the formula evalutates?).

Direct Link (formula evaluated to step before result returned):

```
=VLOOKUP("Megginson ",'\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]Irregularities'!$A:$A,1,FALSE)
```

Dynamic Link (formula evaluated to step before failure):

```
=VLOOKUP("Megginson ", "'\\samnedfsn1\common\Exception - Frequent Access Spreadsheets\Customer Services\Irregularities spreadsheets\2017-18 irregularities spreadsheets\[YH Irregularities Spreadsheet 2017-18.xlsx]Irregularities'!$A:$A",1,FALSE)
```

Now I figure that the issue is with trying to generate the external sheet reference via concatenation, however I have absolutely no idea how to amend the code so the links generate correctly (assuming that is what's going wrong). If someone can help me by telling me what's going wrong I would be incredibly grateful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Excel's [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261) function serves to such purposes - it returns the reference, which you can make up by concatenating (`&`) your file names/paths and tab names.